# getUserMedia() in PWA on iOS 11.3.1

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, getusermedia

I'm trying to build a PWA of my webapp. My webapp makes use of getUserMedia to let the user make a picture. the webapp works as expected. the browser asks permission to access the camera and if a user accepts it, the app continues to work. Now, I made a PWA which works except for the camera. The user doesn't get a prompt to give access to its camera which is where I think is the problem. Is there any way to trigger the camera access:

```
   let constraints = {
       video: {
           facingMode: "user"
       },
       audio: false
   };

navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then(function (stream) {
        track = stream.getTracks()[0];
        cameraView.srcObject = stream;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.error("Oops. Something is broken.", error);
    });
```

like such inside a PWA? or is this not possible (yet)? If not, are there any plans for PWA's on iOS to have this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

On your manifest.json file, you probably have `"display": "standalone"`. If you change it to `browser` it should work. I'm facing the same problem now and it seems that iOS doesn't allow access to webrtc outside Safari main view

Comment: I believe that this is possible now. I am using display:fullscreen and successfully using the camera