# Camera not working on iOS, error in getUserMedia

Tags: ios, iphone, vue.js, camera, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to understand and I'm pretty sure a problem is not in what it telling me.

I am building a PWA with Vue.js. When I init a camera, it does not work on iOS (v11+). I tried many variations, but have no idea what's going on behind and how to properly debug a compiled code in Safari Developer tool (breakpoints just won't work).

here is the code:

```
async init () {

    // Media Device settings
    const constraints = {
      audio: false,
      video: {
        facingMode: (this.camera.mode === 'front') ? 'user' : { exact: 'environment' },
        width: this.camera.size.width,
        height: this.camera.size.height
      }
    }

    try {
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
      this.tracks = stream.getVideoTracks()
      this.video.srcObject = stream

      // Toggle the camera state
      this.toggleCamera(true)

      // Check for realtime validation
      if (this.realtime) {
        this.validatePhotoRealtime()
      }
    } catch (e) {
      this.handleErrorMessage(`getUserMedia error: ${e.name}`, e)
    }
  }
```

And here is what I get in console window:

`Trying to call getUserMedia from an insecure document.`

[image]

Any idea how to debug this error ?

**==== UPDATE ====**

While developing on localhost and having no https available for development environment, doing `yarn server` and connecting to served IP over network

[image]

I've enabled an option for WebRTC:
[image]

But it does not help.

Comment: You need to be serving the application over https.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter - Question updated! it worked before, with the same configuration like shown in my question block. But suddenly it stoped.

Comment: Are you mixing http and https? that kind of error usually happens when you do this, like, main page is on https, and you try and go for a library under an http route, it will fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately apple dose not allow the use of WebRTC when you use your app as a PWA.
Take a look at this links.

[getUserMedia() in PWA on iOS 11.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50535580/getusermedia-in-pwa-on-ios-11-3-1)

https://github.com/webrtc/samples/issues/933

Comment: Thanks, I will check it, but I believe it's working. I've made a github repo page for this to, check this out on iPhone. https://danieltorscho.github.io/vue-pwa-camera
Even with `manifest` `standalone` mode - it worked.

Comment: I try it and it didn't work, probably there is a problem with the start_url. I am getting a 404 when I open it as a PWA. Have a look, If you made it work I am very interested!!

Comment: Camera support for standalone was fixed in iOS 13.5.1. https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=185448

Answer (score 1):

In last version of safari you can allow insecure sites from the web inspector window. See this response : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59770868/2440064